# How can i pass value back using Get.back() from page2 to page1

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-get

Here are what i am trying

1. Page 1 - Ask to select a value.
2. Page 2 select the value from the list.
3. Once value is selected, navigate back to Page 1
4. the selected values should show in the page1.

a code snippet will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a variety of different solutions...

Here is one approach:

see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

What you wrote could be a classic case for "**Lifting State Up**". You save the value in the parent widget of Page 1 and Page 2, the parent value is a stateful widget. You can pass the value and the handler (selecting the value) to page 1 and page 2 with the constructor (simplest solution). The "value" is stored in the parent widget (exactly: in the State object of the parent) as a state variable.

---

==== EDIT ====

Sorry, never used GetX and just discovered that GetX state management  has the concept of avoiding Stateful Widgets *at all*.... (don't work with the Flutter toolkit, let's fight it ;-)

Maybe you can try according to this blog post, it shows you a simple solution: (without Obx)
https://helloyogita.medium.com/flutter-state-management-with-getx-5b8cad6a33f7

GetX uses GetxController classes to store the state vals.

```
//----------
/storing the state value
class CounterController extends GetxController {
  int counter = 0;

  void increment() {
    counter++;
    modify();
  }
}



//---------------
//setting the value in another widget


final counterCtl = CounterController();
....
onPressed: () { 
    counterCtl.increment();
    }



//------------------
//using the value

class DemoGetBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<CounterController>(
        init: CounterController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Text("Value = ${controller.counter}");
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: If i am using getx, the issue what i get is Get.argumant is null on Page1 as it was not loaded page2 yet